How can I ensure that I am transmitting at a certain baud rate using GNURadio, PlutoSDR, and GMSK modulation? What is the relation to samples/symbol?

I am new to signal processing, so this post may not be properly phrased, but I am attempting to use GNUradio to send a GMSK-modulated string to a CubeSat that my club is ground testing. The satellite is looking for a 12.5kBps GMSK signal. My setup uses Netcat to send a string to the UDP Source block, which is then modulated and sent to the PlutoSDR. I decided to use UDP instead of a file source because there was some "stuttering" in the signal when using it. However, the satellite sees nothing when I transmit, even though I have confirmed that Pluto is sending a something, so I assume that what I am transmitting is misconfigured in some way.
I have found a lot of conflicting information online about how samples/symbol and the baud rate of the transmission are related, and how to determine what samples/symbol should be in the first place. One other thing is the BT variable, which is described as "Gaussian filter bandwidth / symbol time". Would 12.5k be the filter bandwidth? For now, my sample rate is simply 12,500 multiplied by the samples/symbol of the GMSK modulation block. Would the resulting signal from the PlutoSDR therefore be at 12.5k baud? Are there any other obvious issues with my flowgraph? I apologize for the broad nature of these questions, and thank you for taking the time to read this.
